# Print a div in a chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-app

I'm building a chrome app at the moment which needs a print function.
I've been searching the developer.chrome.com website, but I can't seem to find how I an enable this.

The first version was just a normal webapp. I printed using the "printThis" library (https://github.com/jasonday/printThis).

I was amazed to see this breaks when run in a chrome webapp. So then I tried printing the whole page with window.print(). But apperantly, this also doesn't work in packaged apps.

So now I'm stuck, I can't seem to find how I can enable printing from a packaged app, let alone printing a div.

Answer (score 0):

printThis doesn't work because it is using features which are forbidden by  [Chrome Apps CSP policy](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

As for `window.print()` it works in Canary and Developer channels, I'm not sure about Stable. So if it doesn't work now it will be fixed with next release.

Comment: @WouterVandenneucker In source code of printThis I saw some iframe creation with `javascript` protocol. Also it is trying to create iframes (and this is forbidden as well - http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html)